# when i changed language of iphone its causing crash?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, localization, nsmutablestring

```
   let initialStr = "To see information for today, please"

        let tempFontSize = UIUtils.getFontForApproprieteField(.subHeadline).font.pointSize

        let tealDict = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: tempFontSize), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.LTColor()]
        let linkAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.LTColor(), NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSNumber(value: false as Bool)]
        errorLbl?.linkAttributes = linkAttributes
        errorLbl?.delegate = self

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: AppMessage.emptyWidget, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: tempFontSize)])
        attributedString.addAttributes(tealDict, range: NSMakeRange(initialStr.length+1,3))
        errorLbl?.attributedText = attributedString

        let rangeT : NSRange = (AppMessage.emptyWidget as NSString).range(of: " add")
        errorLbl?.addLink(to: URL(string: "https://www.google.co.in/")!, with: rangeT)
```

i want to make **Add** which is after **please** as hyperlink . Its working in all devices except when we change the language this line causes crash .

when i changed language of iphone this line causing crash ?

languageChange :- English -> Hindi

crash :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'

Comment: That means range you are passing is not correct. You need to debug it.

Comment: debugged. The nslocalised string key was not having corrosponding value thats why .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppMessage.emptyWidget was a localised string but the key was not having corresponding value in localised.string thats why range issue was there .
Added the value of key and app works fine.